# Querying custom fields from JIRA Rest API and PHP

Tags: php, rest, laravel, curl, jira

I'm attempting to use PHP and cURL to connect to the REST API of my company's JIRA instance.

I can display custom fields that look like this:

```
customfield_10203":"16-204-012"
```

By querying in PHP like this:

```
$issue->fields->customfield_10203
```

However, the issues I'm querying also have custom fields returned this way by the REST API:

```
"customfield_11100":{"self":"http://192.0.0.228:8080/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10600","value":"Open","id":"10600"}
```

But when I attempt to query them in the same way I get a PHP error:

> htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

When I try to query further down, like `$issue->fields->customfield_11100->value`, I get the following:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$customfield_11100

How do I get the "value" or "self" or "id" information from the custom field? Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of `dd($issue);`?

Comment: @Bogdan I edited it a bit but here it is [in Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/rqPb1qy5). One thing I notice when looking at this output is that I can access array fields like this `$issue->fields->priority->name` but I cannot do `$issue->fields->customfield_11100->value` even though apparently it is a similar kind of field.

Comment: Strange, could you do a `var_dump` instead of `dd`, because that would print out data types as well. That would at least show if `customfield_11100` is a `stdClass` instance or something else.

Comment: OK this is getting annoying. The var_dump of `$issue->fields->customfield_11100` says `object(stdClass)#998 (3) { ["self"]=> string(58) "http://redacted/" ["value"]=> string(4) "Open" ["id"]=> string(5) "10600" }`. What's funny is that I can `dd($issue->fields->customfield_11100->value` and get the exact output I want: "Open." But when I echo it or anything else it returns the errors above.